# how the captcha images generated?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, captcha, codeigniter-3

Controller is given below. how the captcha images is generated in the folder.anyone can help? here the image folder paths are given. but how the images automatically generated?

```
  function getCaptchImage(){
            $response['captcha'] = $this->generateCaptcha();

            echo json_encode($response);
            exit;
        }



     function generateCaptcha() {

        //Load Captcha helper
        $this->load->helper('captcha');

            $vals = array(
                'word'       => 'Security Key words',
                'img_path'   => './uploads/captcha/',
                'img_url'    => base_url() . 'captcha/',
                'img_width'  => 200,
                'img_height' => 50,
                'expiration' => 7200,
            );

            /* Generate the captcha */
            $captcha = create_captcha($vals);

            /* Store the captcha value (or 'word') in a session to retrieve later */
            $this->session->set_userdata('captchaWord', $captcha['word']);
            $this->session->set_userdata('captchaImage', $captcha['image']);

            return $captcha['image'];
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can find all the information about the Captcha helper at the following URL https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/captcha_helper.html